# C#: I need Help in Creating valid ISBN property

Tags: c#, properties

I have a Book class with a constructor which has a isbn parameter:

```
public class Book
    public Book (long ISBN)
        {
           this.ISBN = isbn; 
        }
```

ISBN is 10-13 digit number - each book has unique ISBN, which is stored in a private backing field (auto-generated by the compiler).
I need to code the read-only property which will return ISBN number. This number is supplieid as an argument to the constructor I wrote above.

```
public long ISBN { get; } // Need to Fix/Finish this code block
```

I need Help to Finalize / correct this code block. Do I need to somehow enforce/validate the 10-13 digit number condition for this property (maybe by somehow using microsoft's BarcodeSymbologies.Isbn Property)? Thank you in advance.

c#

Comment: ISBNs are **not** integer-numbers.  They should be treated as preformatted strings of decimal characters.

Comment: @Dai https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodesymbologies.isbn?view=winrt-22000 
why did Microsoft gave it uint type then?

Comment: [That property you're linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodesymbologies.isbn?view=winrt-22000) does not store an ISBN or EAN; it's just (essentially) an exported const value, like an `enum` or _magic number_ used to refer to the *concept* of an ISBN or EAN in some other schema. See how it's a `static` property?

Comment: @Dai I see. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Validate Input

It depends on what kind of validation result you need.

To ensure you get no invalid data, you can simply add the check when writing the data, so you could add it in the constructor:

```
public class Book
    public Book (long isbn)
        {
           if(!IsIsbnValid(isbn)) throw new ArgumentException( message: "Invalid ISBN", paramName: nameof(isbn) );
           this.ISBN = isbn; 
        }
```

On the other hand, when working with e.g. asp.net, you want to show error messages to users etc... in this case, you could create a custom validation attribute as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-attributes

Note the difference: In the first case, we ensure no invalid object can be created. In the second case we allow the object to be created but have an ecosystem that allows to us check if the object data is valid.

### Validating ISBNs

ISBN numbers have some rules like length and afaik a checksum. The validation rules are simple and a google search will give you all details. S.a. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

### ISBN Data Type

While ISBNs are numbers it can be more practical to treat them as strings, esp. when dealing with user input. You typically don't want to search for ISBNs "greater than 1234". If you need "starts with", "contains", ... conditions, these may work better with a string data type. If you use a string, I'd recommend to remove the optional separators.

### C# Records

It looks like you're working with immutable types. In this case, you could use the new C# records to simplify your code:

```
public record Book(string ISBN);
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record

Comment: Upvoted for use of immutability.

Comment: And change `long isbn` to `string isbn`, also consider cases where ISBN values exist in other EAN.URN namespaces (like "bookland"). There's dozens of GS1 papers about the topic:

Comment: Better yet: _represent ISBNs using a refinement type_!

Comment: I like the separate types but one should keep in mind, that this may need additional effort to make it work with serialization or e.g. if we want to use such types in asp.net routes etc...

Comment: "needs additional effort" - quite the understatement :) Custom refinement-types in C#/.NET are simultaneously often the best way to represent domain rules in a program's model, but also introduce heaps of tedious low-value work that arguably C# _should_ be more than capable of doing by itself for us, but still doesn't, _\*grumble\*_